# An estimate for simple functions.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $f\colon [a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Let $\{\Delta_n\}$ be a sequence of partition of $[a,b]$: $$\Delta_n:=\{a=x_0^n<x_1^n<\cdots < x_{k_n}^n=b\}.$$ Then $$[a,b]=\bigcup_{k=1}^{k_n} I_k^n,\quad I_k^n:=[x_{k-1}^n, x_k^n]\quad (k=1, \dots k_n).$$ Let us suppose that $\Delta_n\subseteq \Delta_{n+1}$ and $|\Delta_n|\to 0$ for $n\to\infty$. We define $$m_k^n:=\inf_{x\in I_k^n}f(x), \quad M_k^n:=\sup_{x\in I_k^n}f(x)$$

$$s_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}m_k^n\chi_{I_k^n},\quad S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}M_k^n\chi_{I_k^n}.$$ Since $f$ is bounded, exists $M>0$ such that $|f|\le M$ in $I$.

> Why $|s_n|\le 2M$ and $|S_n|\le 2M$?

Comment: You have $|M_k^n|,|m_k^n|\leq M$, so...

Comment: @Jose27Thanks. Now, $|s_n|\le\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}|m_k^n|\chi_{I_k^n}\le M\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}\chi_{I_k^n}$. However, I don't understand how I can conclude from here.

Comment: @JackJ. only two intervals ever overlap at once in a given partition (at the endpoints), so $\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}\chi_{I_k^n}\leq 2$ everywhere.